# Direct Proof: $A\subseteq\bigcap_{n\lt\omega}f^n[A]\cup\bigcup_{n\lt\omega}f^n[A]\setminus f^n[B]\cup \bigcup_{n\lt\omega} f^n[B]\setminus f^{n+1}[A]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals

In the course of trying to prove a larger claim, I want to demonstrate **directly** that $A = P \cup H_0 \cup H_1 \cup H_2 ... \cup \  K_0 \cup K_1 \cup K_2 ...$

where $P = \bigcap_{n \lt \omega}f^n[A] = \bigcap_{n \lt \omega}f^n[B]$,

$H_n = f^n[A] \setminus f^n[B]$, and $K_n = f^n[B] \setminus f^{n+1}[A]$.

Here is the extra information that is relevant:

$f:  A \xrightarrow{1-1} B$, and the notation $f^n$ simply refers to $n$ iterations of the function $f$ (with $f^0$ representing $I_A$)

$A \supseteq B \supseteq f[A] \supseteq f[B] \supseteq f^2[A] \supseteq f^2[B] \supseteq...$

Previously, I have also proven that $P$, $H_m$ and $K_n$ are all pairwise disjoint.

Seeing as the one direction is fairly trivial, I have condensed the desired proof into the following form:

> $A \subseteq \bigcap_{n \lt \omega}f^n[A] \ \cup \ \bigcup_{n\lt \omega}f^n[A] \setminus f^n[B] \  \cup \ \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} f^n[B] \setminus f^{n+1}[A] $

---

I have successfully demonstrated  $A \subseteq \bigcap_{n \lt \omega}f^n[A] \ \cup \ \bigcup_{n\lt \omega}f^n[A] \setminus f^n[B] \  \cup \ \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} f^n[B] \setminus f^{n+1}[A] $. **However**, I could only do so using a **proof by contradiction**.

Specifically, I assumed $A \nsubseteq \bigcap_{n \lt \omega}f^n[A] \ \cup \ \bigcup_{n\lt \omega}f^n[A] \setminus f^n[B] \  \cup \ \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} f^n[B] \setminus f^{n+1}[A] $ and arrived at a contradiction.

My set up for this was $\exists x \in A \Big(x \notin P \land x \notin \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} H_n \land x \notin \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} K_n \Big )$

$x \notin P \leftrightarrow \exists x \in \omega \Big (x \notin f^n[A] \Big) \land \exists n \in \omega \Big (x \notin f^n[B]\Big)$

$x \notin \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} H_n \leftrightarrow \forall n \in \omega \Big ( x \notin f^n[A] \Big ) \lor \forall n \in \omega \Big (x \in f^n[B] \Big) $

$x \notin \bigcup_{n\lt \omega} K_n \leftrightarrow \forall n \in \omega \Big ( x \notin f^n[B] \Big ) \lor \forall n \in \omega \Big (x \in f^{n+1}[A] \Big) $

The contradictions that arise from these three simultaneous statements are straightforward.

---

*I am really at loss on how to prove this claim directly.*

I've played around with it quite a bit using a working example of $A=\mathbb N$, $B=\mathbb N \setminus \{2,3\}$ and $f$ being the *natural number square function* (where $n \mapsto n^2$)...where, for example, $P$ equals $\{0,1\}$

I have some visual intuition about how these sets partition $A$:

[image: Visual Partitioning]

If anyone could offer some input on **how to formulate a direct proof**, I would greatly appreciate it. Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$C_n=\begin{cases}
f^{n/2}[A],&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
f^{(n-1)/2}[B],&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\,,
\end{cases}$$

so that $C_0=A$, $C_1=B$, and $C_n\supseteq C_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\omega$. For each $x\in A\setminus P$ let $n(x)=\min\{k\in\omega:x\notin C_k\}$; clearly $n(x)>0$, and

$$\begin{align*}
x\in C_{n(x)-1}\setminus C_{n(x)}&=\begin{cases}
f^{k-1}[B]\setminus f^k[A],&\text{if }n(x)=2k\\
f^k[A]\setminus f^k[B],&\text{if }n(x)=2k+1
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
K_{k-1},&\text{if }n(x)=2k\\
H_k,&\text{if }n(x)=2k+1\,.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$A\setminus P\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\omega}H_n\cup\bigcup_{n\in\omega}K_n\,,$$

and the result follows.

Comment: Crafty! Thank you, thank you. If you're willing to offer some insight, I have a question for you. When trying to figure out how to formulate a direct approach, the problem I ran into was effectively not knowing how to say "let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$ and prove that this arbitrary element of $A$ resides in one of the three aforementioned sets". I knew that I needed to be more SPECIFIC about the different ways that $x$ could reside within $A$...but this essentially led to an infinite disjunction: $x \in A \lor x \in B \lor x \in f[A] \lor x \in f[B] ...$.

Comment: The issue with this is that I obviously cannot go case by case on an infinite list. So your work around was to collapse this infinite disjunction into a collection of finite symbols using the functions $n$ and $C$, which allowed F.O.L. to "do what it does best". Your final statement seems to amount to $\forall x \in A \setminus P \Big (x \in C_{n(x)-1} \setminus C_{n(x)} \Big )$...which therefore implies your conclusion. Is that sort of the right idea?

Comment: @S.Cramer: You’re welcome. Yes, you could paraphrase the final result that way. I’d say that what I actually did, though, was provide a way to identify and specify the specific $H_n$ or $K_n$ to which any given member of $A\setminus P$ belongs.