# What is the relationship between an existential statement $\exists(x)\varphi(x)$ and the phrase "can be calculated"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I recently read a proof that made me question the relationship between an existential claim $\exists x \varphi(x)$ and "can be calculated". The exact proof can be found as the answer to the post here --> [Direct Proof: $A\subseteq\bigcap_{n\lt\omega}f^n[A]\cup\bigcup_{n\lt\omega}f^n[A]\setminus f^n[B]\cup \bigcup_{n\lt\omega} f^n[B]\setminus f^{n+1}[A]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988482/direct-proof-a-subseteq-bigcap-n-lt-omegafna-cup-bigcup-n-lt-omegafna), but I will summarize the part that specifically led to the question I will ask in *this current* post.

Without going into all of the detail, there was a starting set $A$ and a nested chain of subsets that worked as follows:

$A \supseteq B \supseteq f[A] \supseteq f[B] \supseteq f^2[A] \supseteq f^2[B] \supseteq...$

Importantly, this chain spanned to infinity (i.e. $n \lt \omega$).

In this chain, $f$ is an injective function $f:  A \xrightarrow{1-1} B$, and the notation $f^n$ simply refers to $n$ iterations of the function $f$ (with $f^0$ representing $I_A$).

---

In the aforementioned post, the author develops a function $N$ that takes an arbitray element $x$ in $A$ and maps it to the last such subset that **does NOT** contain it. For example, let's say that $f^n[A]$ happens to be the first appearance of the element $x$ (i.e. $x$ is not an element of *any subset* of $f^n[A]$). Then $N(x) = f^n[B]$

...or, alternatively, let's say that $f^n[B]$ happens to be the first appearance of the element $x$. Then $N(x)=f^{n+1}[A]$.

In order to prove that such a function exists (*it does*), I confirmed a formula with the following basic structure: $\forall x \in A \exists ! y \varphi(x,y)$.

When I thought a little more about this, though, I realized that if someone handed me an actual number that was in the function $N$'s domain (e.g. $2$), and asked me, "Where does $N$ take $2$?", I wouldn't know how to respond.

It seems like my only option would be to start at set $A$ and begin my decent down the infinitely nested chain of subsets until I spotted the first occasion of $2$'s disappearance. I guess with enough time, such a method could be carried out...so perhaps this *is* "calculatable".

**Conversely**, however, I can imagine some variant of the above proof where I am not working with $n \lt \omega$ (which has the perk of a minimal element) but *instead* $\mathbb Z$...or maybe a transfinite ordinal "bigger" than $\omega$. In these other cases, it seems like there may *not* be a calculation that can be provided, at least with any guaranteed chance of working.

So what exactly does "$\exists x \varphi(x)$ tell me? Is this FOL statement synonymous with "Depending on the circumstance, the thing may be calculatable" without leaving any inkling about *how* it can be calculated?

Comment: See [Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/): in classical mathematics we can prove a statement $∃xφ(x)$ without any information about the "value" $a$ such that $φ(a)$ holds. The proof must derive $∃xφ(x)$ from the fact that $\forall x \lnot φ(x)$ implies a contradiction

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so in "classical mathematics", if I show an existential statement to be true, all I gain from this is the knowledge that "the negated version of this claim is a contradiction"? i.e. the existential statement says nothing about one's ability to construct the object?

Comment: Not necessarily... we can prove it by contradiction. But we can prove it also directly: obviously, if we know that $2$ satisfies the equation $(x^2=4)$, this is enough to assert that $\exists x (x^2=4)$

Comment: @S.Cramer " the existential statement says nothing about one's ability to construct the object" That's **exactly right**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber this may be sort of a "dumb"/misguided question...but then what is the purpose of an existential statement? What is the purpose of logic? I always thought that painting the landscape with true and false statements ultimately gave way to "application". In that sense, I assumed that "truth" paved the road for construction. Is the following at least true: $\text{ object can be constructed } \rightarrow \text { object exists }?$

Comment: @S.Cramer "What is the purpose of logic? I always thought that painting the landscape with true and false statements ultimately gave way to "application". In that sense, I assumed that "truth" paved the road for construction." This is vague enough that I don't really know how to respond, and at least to a certain extent I disagree, but it doesn't matter: even if you don't care about "pure existential" statements, that doesn't mean that they're meaningless or even useless to you, it just means that they're *not the end of the story for you*.

Comment: One line I like is the following: in classical logic at least, we're looking for a framework for talking about mathematics which is **minimally loaded**, since this lets us **say more**. Broadly speaking, if you care about constructions then there are *three* possible answers to the question "Is there an $x$ such that $P$?", namely: "there is no such $x$," "there is such an $x$ and here's how to construct one," and "there is such an $x$ but we have no way of constructing it." Using a minimally-loaded language lets us distinguish between the first and third options.

Comment: @NoahSchweber great responses. Thank you. I'm trying to refrain from engaging in a philosophical line of questioning, but it seems...confusing...to think that one can assert, "there is such an $x$ but we have no way of constructing it". It's like sitting on the peak of one mountain and seeing an object on a neighboring peak but having no way to get to that neighboring peak in order to touch the object.

Comment: @S.Cramer "It's like sitting on the peak of one mountain and seeing an object on a neighboring peak but having no way to get to that neighboring peak in order to touch the object." That doesn't sound particularly weird, just unsatisfying. I think things may become simpler if you consider instead statements of the form "$\forall x\exists y(P(x,y))$" where there's no uniform process for getting an appropriate $y$ from a given $x$, since here there's a bit more structure to play with. E.g. "For every computer program $P$ there is some $n$ such that if $P$ halts, it halts by stage $n$."

Comment: (This is called "[Markov's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle)," incidentally, and plays an important role in constructive mathematics.) It should be pretty obvious that this is true in the "bare" sense, but if we take "construct" to mean "*compute*" we clearly can't have a single constructive process which gives each $P$ an appropriate $n$. I don't see anything confusing here, it's just the way things have played out, and making our language more loaded wouldn't change the situation but just make it harder to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says nothing more than that there is at least one object with the desired property. This object may or may not be constructible (in whatever sense), but all "$\exists x\varphi(x)$" asserts is bare existence.

Depending on what you want from logic this may feel unsatisfying. But note that **being able to express bare existential claims does not prevent us from *also* being able to express more complicated constructibility claims** (although again one would need to specify what "construct" means - is the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) "constructible"?). I would argue that in fact it's the other way around: more loaded language has more difficulty expressing finer distinctions.

This is how I personally think of classical logic most of the time: it's a drastically, almost *unnaturally*, bare framework in which each assertion means the bare minimum that it has to. This makes it **perfect** for developing really complicated loaded ideas  because there's no danger of "contamination" from background intentionalities. For example, I would rather develop a theory of "constructive truth" within a classical framework than develop a theory of "classical truth" within a constructive framework, since in the latter approach I would be worried that my background constructivity was interfering with my notion of classicality. I'm not saying that the latter can't be done - it absolutely can - just that *at the beginning* I would have a worry which would not be present, at least for me, if the former approach were being followed.

(Of course the previous paragraph can be **severely** deconstructed, and the words "I" and "most" were carefully chosen in its first sentence. But I really do think that there's a lot to it.)

Comment: For a while now, I have thought of the $\forall$ and $\exists$ quantifiers as behaving like slot machines, in the sense that when they are invoked, such as in $\exists x \varphi(x) $, the $x$ in $\varphi(x)$ is effectively toggled across every known element in the universe (sort like of how a slot machine spins around and around, presenting different symbols to the player). Given all of your feedback to my comments, it seems like my analogy to slot machines does not capture how truly DIFFERENT the quantifiers' "machinery" is from that of a slot machine.

Comment: Is there a better analogy to understand HOW quantifiers "roam the landscape" where all of the objects of the domain of discourse reside?

Comment: @S.Cramer I think it's a bad idea to think of quantifiers as *acting* in any way at all. To my mind bringing agency into the picture invites the existence/constructibility confusion in the first place. The point instead is that the logical apparatus is purely **descriptive**. That said, one analogy I like is that you're listening to *someone else* tell you what's out there: even if you think that their ability to be certain that $\exists x\varphi(x)$ entails their ability to *find* an $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$, there's no reason to infer that *you yourself* should be able to find such an $x$.